# Недопустимый параметр для Setlocal

Tags: cmd

Использую нейросети для upscaling'а спрайтов из старых игр и скриптом создаю специальный текстовый *.def-файл с перечислением файлов из папки и добавлением в строку пары параметров.
Использую такой скрипт

```
 setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion for %%f in (tile*.png) do ( set tmp=%%f if "%%f"=="!tmp:~0,8!.png" ( echo texture !tmp:~4,4! { pal 0 { file "upscale/%%f" nocompress nodownsize }} >> new.def ) else ( echo texture !tmp:~4,4! { pal !tmp:~9,-4! { file "upscale/%%f" nocompress nodownsize }} >> new.def ) )
```

Однако выполнение этого скрита выдаёт ошибку - Недопустимый параметр команды Setlocal.
В чём проблема? Скрипт отсюда
https://upscale.wiki/wiki/Upscaling_Build_Engine_Games

В папке со скриптом лежат png-файлы с названиями tile****.png
Скрипт всего-лишь должен создать текстовый файл с расширением *.def, где для каждого файла будет своя строка с текстом вида

> texture 0001 {  pal 0 { file "upscale/tile0001.png" nocompress
> nodownsize }}

Answer (score 0):

Не работает, т.к. надо переносы строк вставить (отформатировать):

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for %%f in (tile*.png) do (
  set tmp=%%f
  if "%%f"=="!tmp:~0,8!.png" (
    echo texture !tmp:~4,4! { pal 0 { file "upscale/%%f" nocompress nodownsize }} >> new.def
  ) else (
    echo texture !tmp:~4,4! { pal !tmp:~9,-4! { file "upscale/%%f" nocompress nodownsize }} >> new.def
  )
)
```

В источнике просто форматирование потерялось.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Теперь заработало